# Can't understand the response of posting data in the server using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I use AFNetworking to post an array comprising the contact details in the device to the server. I don't understand the response that I got back.   Given below is my code.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"UserContacts": contactsArray};
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:baseUrl parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE : %@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {    
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

The response is

```
 RESPONSE : <4e6f2044 61746120 55706c6f 61646564>
```

Can anyone please explain what this response is. Is this the problem of ios or php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means "No Data Uploaded". That what you'll obtain by doing `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. But it seems that you have an issue about the serializer settings.

Comment: The response you got is in NSData format , you need to convert it back to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by removing this line

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: Cocoa error 3840 is a JSON parsing error (if you search on Stack Overflow for it you'll come across this existing question about).

I suggest you run your output JSON from your web service through a JSON validator to check that it is actually compliant with the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Place breakpoint in the `success` callback and when it hit, debug area will show contents of `responseObject` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

to

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/json"];
```

My way of calling API using AFNetworing is

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"action": @"actionOfAPI",
                         @"Param1": Param1,
                         @"Param2": Param2};

[manager GET/POST:kBaseUrl parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

If you are getting same error then just search for 'text/json' in your project and change it as below at all places inside AFNetworking classes.

```
self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", nil];
```